# Migrating ownership from macos

Tags: permissions, sudo, macosx, chown, ownership

I switched from Macos to Ubuntu, now I am trying to own my mac homefolder with Ubuntu. I thought to be smart and use the same username (ruut) and password for the new account and homefolder, but that didn't do the trick.

I plugged in an external usb disk and navigated to the Macos 'users' folder and try to change the ownership of the whole 'ruut' folder

```
ruut@ruuts-linux:/media/ruut/Yosemite kopie/Users$ sudo chown -R ruut: ruut
```

After the password, the computer went to work and appeared to be changing everything. But then checking reality afterwards, I am still not the owner of the old homefolder and everything in it.
What am I typing wrong?

Also tried some other things:

```
ruut@ruuts-linux:/media/ruut/Yosemite kopie/Users$ sudo chown -R ruut /media/ruut/Yosemite kopie/Users/ruut
```

[sudo] password for ruut:
chown: cannot access '/media/ruut/Yosemite': No such file or directory
chown: cannot access 'kopie/Users/ruut': No such file or directory

```
ruut@ruuts-linux:/media/ruut/Yosemite kopie/Users$ sudo chown -R ruut /ruut
```

chown: cannot access '/ruut': No such file or directory

No succes here either.

Comment: I do not know anything about macos, so no answer. But on linux the username is not relevant when migrating. What is relevant is the user id. (https://www.fosslinux.com/39230/what-is-uid-in-linux-and-how-to-find-and-change-it.htm)

Comment: If the external storage device is still using AFPS (or HFS+) then Linux ownership and permissions rules will not work in any meaningful way. You will need to copy the data to your Ubuntu-made storage to reclaim ownership.

Comment: Yes thanks, that must be it. The external disk is an HFS+.